# Is this sentence grammatically correct? A ten pounds sugar are in the kitchen

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> A ten pounds of sugar are in the kitchen.

Why don't they use "is" instead of "are"?

Comment: That’s not the only problem with the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No.
"A ten pounds of sugar are in the kitchen" is incorrect because of two varying factors.

First is the article "A". This article is used to signify a singular subject, which in your case does not conform to the linking verb "are" - denotes a plural subject.

If you want it to mean as "many(ten) pounds of sugar in the kitchen." I advise that you remove the said article and use a storage unit to satisfy the to-be verb "are".

Ten pounds of sacks of sugar are in the kitchen.

Or replace it with "is", because sugar in plethora is considered an uncountable noun.

Ten pounds of sugar is in the kitchen

"A ten-pound sack of sugar is in the kitchen" is also acceptable.

I'm not an expert either, but this is my insight on this.
Please correct me if necessary.

Comment: "There is ten pounds of sugar in the kitchen."

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about demonstrative pronouns. Thank You!